# How to update "updatedAt" on main table after child table with foreign key updated or created on sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have main table "flow" and other table that connect to flow table with foreign key.

How can I update "flow" table "updateAt" column when the other table create new data or update data.

Example:

I have "uplodadFiles" table that connect to the flow table with flowID foreign key, now when new file uploaded to "uplodadFiles" I need to update "flow" table "updateAt".
What is the best way to do this? Hook? Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using database triggers for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, Hook on sequelize, but how? put every model trigger for update the main table? @Shadow

Comment: Database triggers are not part of sequelize, those are declared in mysql.

Comment: But if I already use sequelize why not use Hook instead ? @Shadow

Comment: Database triggers can keep your flow table updated regardless of the way you insert / update data in the other tables. Plus, you tagged the question with mysql, so I thought you were considering database level solutions. If not, then your question is not relevant for mysql.